# What does 'processor (None)' mean in lshw's output?

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu

I am running a VM on Azure with 4-cores. I typed `lshw -short` and got the following:

```
H/W path      Device     Class      Description

===============================================
                         system     Virtual Machine
/0                       bus        Virtual Machine
/0/0                     memory     64KiB BIOS
/0/5                     processor  Xeon (None)
/0/6                     processor  Xeon (None)
/0/7                     processor  Xeon (None)
/0/8                     processor  Xeon (None)
/0/9                     processor  (None)
/0/a                     processor  (None)
/0/b                     processor  (None)
```

There are in total 64 items in *processor* class. Besides the four *Xeon*s, what are the rest 60 `(None)` processors?